Reading Events from Implementation contract
I own a proxy contract as well as an implementation contract. The implementation contract's function emits an event, but it does not emit the event when it is called from the proxy contract. Using the hardhat framework for testing, the event is not being emitted. What am I missing here? How can I achieve this?
Thank you

The test case is actually failing when tested using to.emit() in Hardhat test.
However, when you check the logs, you can find the event being emitted from the proxy contract function call (i.e., delegate call to the corresponding function of the implementation contract). So, you might use that as a workaround for the same.
Here's a minimal example to test the same:
Solidity Contracts:
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.24;

// Proxy contract
contract MyProxy {
    address public implementation;

    constructor(address _implementation) {
        implementation = _implementation;
    }

    function forwardFunction(uint256 arg) public {
        // Forward the function call to the implementation contract
        (bool success, ) = implementation.delegatecall(
            abi.encodeWithSignature("someFunction(uint256)", arg)
        );
        require(success, "Forwarding failed");
    }

    // Function to upgrade the implementation contract
    function upgradeImplementation(address _newImplementation) public {
        implementation = _newImplementation;
    }
}

// Implementation contract
contract MyImplementation {
    event SomeEvent(uint256 value);

    function someFunction(uint256 arg) public {
        // Do some operations using the argument
        emit SomeEvent(arg);
    }
}

Hardhat Test:
const { expect } = require("chai");

// Describe the test suite
describe("MyProxy", function () {
  let MyProxy;
  let MyImplementation;
  let myProxy;
  let myImplementation;

  // Deploy the contracts before each test
  beforeEach(async function () {
    MyImplementation = await ethers.getContractFactory("MyImplementation");
    myImplementation = await MyImplementation.deploy();

    MyProxy = await ethers.getContractFactory("MyProxy");
    myProxy = await MyProxy.deploy(await myImplementation.getAddress());
  });

  // Test case for deployment
  it("Should deploy the contracts correctly", async function () {
    expect(await myProxy.implementation()).to.equal(await myImplementation.getAddress());
  });

  // Test case for calling forwardFunction and catching the event
  it("Should emit SomeEvent when calling forwardFunction", async function () {
    const arg = 123; // Argument to pass to someFunction

    // // Failing when using to.emit() for testing
    // await expect(myProxy.forwardFunction(arg))
    //   .to.emit(myImplementation, "SomeEvent")
    //   .withArgs(arg);

    const tx = await myProxy.forwardFunction(arg);
    await tx.wait(); // Wait for the transaction to be mined

    // Retrieve transaction receipt
    const receipt = await ethers.provider.getTransactionReceipt(tx.hash);

    // Filter logs for the emitted event
    const event = receipt.logs.find(log => log.topics[0] === ethers.id("SomeEvent(uint256)"));

    // Check if the event exists
    expect(event).to.exist;

    // Decode and verify event parameters
    const decodedEvent = ethers.AbiCoder.defaultAbiCoder().decode(["uint256"], event.data);
    expect(decodedEvent[0]).to.equal(arg);
  });
});

